# How to search specific data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, loopbackjs

it might be silly question to ask but trust me I am beginner to ReactJS . Actually I have implemented logic for search filter in reactjs here I am doing search filter based on state property ( `state have all records` ) it working fine but basically It render all data which are stored in database . I want to search specific data let suppose I have total 80 records in database I want to search specific data , If for example user type `bla` and it record is stored on Id 10 then I just want to render `Id 10` result not like full data which stored in database . I want to render just match data , currently I am using Loopback4 and I am rendering data through API . Could someone please help me how to solve this problem .

Thanks

Sorry : If I made mistake in English Grammar because I am not native speaker

**Code**

```
    class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to be putting the url as an attribute to the `a` tag.

See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) for how to handle api calls properly!

Hope that could help!